# Error message when adding SQL Server to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have been following along with David Gassner's ASP.NET tutorial on Lynda.com and had things going pretty well up until he walked me through adding an SQL server in the Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2012. When following his steps, I receive the following error:

> Unable to add data connection.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have found numerous websites that suggest installing 3 additional programs/add-ons, such as [this site](http://jacksonpushpanathan.blogspot.com/2009/05/unable-to-add-data-connectioncould-not.html).

I have installed all 3 recommended (Native Client, CLR Types, and Management Objects) and restarted the program and my computer, but still nothing seems to work. Any ideas on how I can add the database?

Additional detail: When I test the connection before choosing OK, the test is successful. I am quite new to SQL/Database stuff so please explain as simply as you can, or link to a resource that will help me fix this.

Comment: What you mean by adding? You attach the connection string to your web.config? It shouldn't be a problem if you already installed your SQL Server properly but still comes with the question what you mean by adding?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of where I am, if this answers anything. [link](http://i.imgur.com/NyMiFUx.png)

Comment: I can help you by team viewer remote to help you through better explanation, because the implication can cause many things can't be specified

Comment: How do get you the information for using team viewer remote? have it running now.

Comment: Found a fix. Apparently it was an issue with using Visual Studio 2012. Using Visual Studio 2010 has made everything work perfectly. Original question has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: Great and I vote for this

Comment: but but what if i dont want to uninstal vs 2012? and to use vs 2010?

Comment: You can answer you own question in another answer rather than adding to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mattcoker solved his own problem with the following solution

Problem has been solved by switching to Visual Studio 2010, works without a hitch. Thanks for the speedy responses.

Comment: I thought this question was still opened only to find it had been solved. Posted the answer as CW. If OP adds his own answer, I'll delete this.